# Giving a uislider values from a price delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am currently working to a template but the template is out of date and needs updating. The app i'm making is a property app the client would like to be able to use a **uislider** to be able to choose the minimum and maximum price.

I thought that this would be simple, the client can currently choose the price from a **uipicker** this gets its values from a price delegate.

I have managed to add my **uislider** and a **label** the label changes depending on where the slider is.

I have been racking my brains out all week trying to figure this one thing out. It surely can't be that hard can it?

I have two **uisliders** one from a minimum price and one for a maximum price.

I thought that I could maybe code the slider to values which would be a case statement with the values of the delegate(i don't know how to do this though), Then what ever would be in the label the app would take in to then use as the query to add the minimum and maximum price to the url.

At the moment it keeps defaulting to 500 for a minimum and 0 for a maximum.

Here is my code that i have managed to achieve for the sliders.

```
- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender {

    UISlider *slide = (UISlider *)sender;
    int min = (int)(slide.value);
    //Display min price
    NSString *minprice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", min];

    NSLog(@"min : %@",minprice);

    label_min.text = minprice;


    NSString * priceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
                              [priceDelegate.values objectAtIndex: [_appDelegate int_minPriceV]]];
    [self.tf_price setText:priceString];


}


- (IBAction)sliderMax:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slidetwo = (UISlider *)sender;

    int max = (int)(slidetwo.value);
    //Display max price
    NSString *maxprice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", max];
    NSLog(@"max : %@",maxprice);
    label_max.text = maxprice;

    NSString * priceStringTwo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 [priceDelegate.values2 objectAtIndex: [_appDelegate int_maxPriceV]]];

    [self.tf_priceTwo setText:priceStringTwo];

}
```

I am student who is currently on a internship, I unfortunately have none here to be able to help me go through this, so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to help get you started:

No where in your code are you actually setting the `UISlider` properties for `minimumValue` and/or `maximumValue`. For that reason its resetting to base numbers every time.

Also, im not sure what `_appDelegate` is specially but if its really your app delegate you should get rid of that. You don't want to be calling that in your view controller. From the apple docs:

> The app delegate is a custom object created at app launch time,
>   usually by the UIApplicationMain function. The primary job of this
>   object is to handle state transitions within the app. For example,
>   this object is responsible for launch-time initialization and handling
>   transitions to and from the background.

Lastly, when you're setting your label's text your not accessing a property from what I can see. Make sure you're seeing your label as a property and then set it using `self`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, will defiantly get me started ill work on it now.